# Running sum in PowerBi with DirectQuery

Tags: azure, dax, powerbi

I can't find a way to calculate a running total, without using FILTER.
**Filter** is not supported in PowerBi direct query-mode.

All help is appreciated

A example when **Filter** is allowed:

```
On Hand = CALCULATE( SUM('Table'[QTY]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSelected('Table'),
        'Table'[Date] <= MAX('Table'[Date])
    )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the answer in this thread](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Function-FORMAT-is-not-supported-in-DirectQuery-mode/m-p/19376#M5813) about how to enable all functions in DirectQuery mode. There is also discussion as to the potential performance concerns.

Comment: Thx.. Just what I needed